# Abrir un JDialog desde otro JDialog

Tags: java, jdialog

¿Cómo abrir un **JDialog** desde otro **JDialog** a través del de evento `actionPerfomed()` de tipo `button`?

Tengo un `JFrame` **main** llamado **Index.java**. A partir de él, tengo un `button` que me genera un **JDialog** llamado **Datos_Admin.java**. Hasta ahí bien. En este **Datos_Admin.java** (propiedades del administrador -nombre, password, email- con un `button` llamado `button_restaurar` `actionPerformed()` a partir del cual quiero abrir un **JDialog** llamado **RestaurarPassword.java.**

**Error:**

```
incompatible types: Datos_Admin cannot be converted to Frame.
```

**Datos_Admin.java :**

```
public class Datos_Admin extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    public Datos_Admin(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        ...
    }

    //Evento que intenta abrir el JDialog llamado RestaurarPassword.java.
    private void button_restaurarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        RestaurarPassword rp = new RestaurarPassword(this, true); //ERROR
        rp.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**RestaurarPassword.java:**

```
public class RestaurarPassword extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    public RestaurarPassword(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Bueno... el problema es que tu RestaurarPassword espera un componente de tipo `Frame` y le estás pasando un `JDialog`. En vez de pasar el `this`, almacena el parent de tu Datos_Admin en una variable y pásale esa variable igual que haces en el `super(parent, modal)`, ese *parent* guárdalo, además de pasárselo al super.

Comment: @Benito-B Un ejemplo para entenderlo. Pensé que se realizaba igual que de un JFrame a un JDialog.